# Error in my 'if' statement containing break (wrox ch 3 exercise 4)

Tags: javascript, break

Trying to figure out this times table function...It's not working as there seems to be a problem with the if statement containing break.    Any help would be much appreciated.

```
function writeTimesTable (startNumber, endNumber, multNumber) {
  for (;startNumber <= endNumber; startNumber++) {
    console.log(startNumber  + " * " + multNumber + " = " + startNumber * multNumber + "</br>")
  }
}
/* writeTimesTable(3,4,5) */
var timesTable;

while ( (timesTable = prompt("Enter the times table", -1)) != -1)
  while (isNaN(timesTable) == true) {
  timesTable = prompt(timesTable + "  is not a valid number, please retry", -1);
  };
  if (timesTable == -1) {
  break;
  };

  console.log("<br />The " + timesTable + " times table<br/>)");
  writeTimesTable(timesTable, 1, 12);
```

Comment: *"It's not working"* isn't a very good problem description. What's not working, what *does* it do that it's not supposed to? Does it give you error messages?

Comment: Sending `<br/>` tags to the console won't do anything except print out `<br/>`.

Comment: Formatting your code really helps you to understand what's nested in what and find errors. You are lacking braces `{}` in your outer `while` statement that will give you syntax errors. That is why your code doesn't work. So `while ( (timesTable = prompt("Enter the times table", -1)) != -1) {` and then a matching `}` after your `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I knew it was something simple...sorry for the poor description, I'll make sure I pay more attention to that last time...just was getting frustrated and wanted a quick answer.  Seems to work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're not using brackets in your outer loop. without brackets only the first statement is executed in the loop.

```
while ( (timesTable = prompt("Enter the times table", -1)) != -1){
  while (isNaN(timesTable) == true) {
      timesTable = prompt(timesTable + "  is not a valid number, please retry", -1);
  }
  if (timesTable == -1) {
      break;
  }
}
```